# What does the "(healthy)" string in STATUS stands for?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

What does the "(healthy)" string in STATUS column stands for?

```
user@user:~# docker ps

CONTAINER ID  IMAGE   COMMAND  CREATED   STATUS                   PORTS  NAMES

X             X       X        X         Up 20 hours              X      X

X             X       X        X         Up 21 hours (healthy)    X      X
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's the result of the [`HEALTHCHECK` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck). That instruciton runs a command inside the container every 30 seconds. If the command succeeds, the container is marked healthy. If it fails too many times, it's marked unhealthy.

You can set the interval, timeout, number of retries, and start delay.

The following instruction for a `Dockerfile`, for example, will check that your container responds to HTTP every 5 minutes with a timeout of 3 seconds.

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

You get a `health_status` event when the health status changes. You can follow those and others with [`docker events`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/).

Comment: why `exit 1`? Does the return code (other than 0) matter? If any non-zero code counts as unhealthy than `exit 1` can be omitted, right?

Answer (score 6):

https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/using-docker-native-health-checks/

Normally it's something you launch with, to enable swarm or other services to check on the health of the container.

IE:

```
$ docker run --rm -it \
     --name=elasticsearch \
     --health-cmd="curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cluster/health || exit 1" \
     --health-interval=5s \
     --health-retries=12 \
     --health-timeout=2s \
     elasticsearch
```

see the health checks enabled at runtime?

Answer (score 5):

Means they are using the command: healthcheck

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

When a container has a healthcheck specified, it has a health status in addition to its normal status. This status is initially ***starting***. Whenever a health check passes, it becomes ***healthy*** (whatever state it was previously in). After a certain number of consecutive failures, it becomes ***unhealthy***.

```
**starting**  – Initial status when the container is still starting
**healthy**   – If the command succeeds then the container is healthy
**unhealthy** – If a single run of the  takes longer than the specified 
  timeout then it is considered unhealthy. If a health check fails then the 
  will run retries number of times and will be declared unhealthy 
  if the  still fails.
```

[Reference](https://blog.couchbase.com/docker-health-check-keeping-containers-healthy/)